# Record audio into memorystream then save it into a file

Tags: c#, .net, file, audio, naudio

I'm using NAudio to capture 15 seconds of audio. Like this:

```
MemoryStream bufferedVoice = new MemoryStream();
voiceCapturer = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(OutputDevice);
voiceCapturer.DataAvailable += onVoiceOutputReceived;
voiceCapturer.StartRecording();

private void onVoiceOutputReceived(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    bufferedVoice.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);    
}
```

And after 15 seconds I want to save it to a file, and exit. I tried it like this but it didn't work:

```
var ResourceWaveStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(bufferedVoice, voiceCapturer.WaveFormat);
var SampleProvider = new WaveToSampleProvider(ResourceWaveStream).ToWaveProvider16();
var fileWriter = new WaveFileWriter("output.mp3", SampleProvider.WaveFormat);

byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
while(SampleProvider.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length) > 0)
{
    fileWriter.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
}
fileWriter.Dispose();
```

How can I save the memorystream into a file?

Clarification: I only want to store x seconds of audio in memory. So when the max size is reached, some of the oldest part is removed. Then if I press a button, I want to save the 15 seconds of audio into a file.

Now, my question is how should I store the audio in memory, and then write it to a file?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722028/convert-wasapiloopbackcapture-wav-audio-stream-to-mp3-file

Comment: If not, the issue may be arising from the fact that WAV and MP3 are different, one is lossless and the other is compressed, and if i remember correctly from tinkering with mp3s there can be headers to the data file as well. Could be a 1!=1 compatibility issue.

Comment: i meant to write wav instead of mp3. But that wasn't the problem.

Comment: And no unfortunately that isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using(var fileWriter = new WaveFileWriter("yourOutputFile", SampleProvider.WaveFormat)
{
    ResourceWaveStream.CopyTo(fileWriter);
}
```

Btw, the "using" block is good for you here because it will automatically dispose the writer, allowing the WaveFileWriter to write headers to the file.

Comment: I've created a WaveFileWriter(new WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(ms), voiceCapturer.WaveFormat)) and wrote the sound data to it. After that I copied the memorystream to a proper WaveFileWriter, but it didn't work.

Comment: modified answer, try this out?

Comment: Wait, do I need to pass the memorystream to a ResourceWaveStream before I copy it to a filewriter?

Comment: Yes, if you use ResourseWaveStream you need to convert to it from the memoryStream, this im assuming adds Wave-type formatting and I think you should do this. You could also try to directly copy the MemoryStream to the WaveFileWriter too (skip the new RawSourceWaveStream() part) , but im not sure if the WaveWriter will like that. If you want to try to copy the MemoryStream directly to the writer, be sure to rewind the stream (seek 0) before copying it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally have the solution. First, I copy the sound data directly to the memory stream. And then when I need it, I read the whole memorystream into a `RawSourceWaveStream` and then I pass that to the final `WaveFileWriter`. If anybody is interested in how I did it exactly, then message me.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course, you helped me a lot.(That wasn't sarcastic)